# can I download a file over http that have a space in the name? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, httpwebrequest, download

there is a space after the word Part in the file name I want to download. It looks like http.get doesn't pass the url_path correctly because you can download the file from the browser without any troubles.

any suggestion how I can **download** a file if there is **a space in the file name**?

```
require 'net/http'

url = "http://www.onalllevels.com/2009-12-02TheYangShow_Squidoo_Part 1.flv"

puts url_base = url.split('/')[2]
puts url_path = '/'+url.split('/')[3..-1].join('/')

Net::HTTP.start(url_base) do |http|
  resp = http.get(url_path)
  open("test.flv", "wb") do |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  end
end
puts "Done."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly encode your URL. Something like:

```
require 'uri'
val = URI.escape("my parameter value")
```

Comment: @Beaner: could you add this code to your answer? `require 'uri';
puts URI.escape('url to encode')`

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the space with a `+` or a `%20`.